# retreive value to user by form in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, encryption

Hello guys i have coded a script which returns the encrypted value of a string..The php code is

## file.php

```
function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) {
   $output = false;

   $key = 'My strong random secret key';





$iv = md5(md5($key));



if( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
       $output = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);


     $output = base64_encode($output);



}
   else if( $action == 'decrypt' ){


$output = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

   $output = rtrim($output, "");



 }


return $output;

}

$plain_txt = "This is my plain text";

$encrypted_txt = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $plain_txt);

echo "Encrypted Text = $encrypted_txt\n";

echo "<br />";

    $decrypted_txt = encrypt_decrypt('decrypt', $encrypted_txt);

echo "Decrypted Text = $decrypted_txt\n";
```

This code returns the encrypted text of "This is my plain text"

My form.html file is ..

```
<form action="file.php" method="get">
  Enter the word to encrypt : <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
 Encrypted text is  : <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

what i need is that when a user types the string he wants he must get the corresponding encrypted text of the string he have inserted in the field ..I know this can be done with sql ..Please help me in giving me some ideas ..Since am a newbie in php and mysql development

Any help would be appreciated ..Thanks ..:)

Comment: `i have coded a script which returns the encrypted value of a string` ... You have coded something ... `bad`

Comment: didnt get you ?...that php file just return the encrypted value of string .whats it wrong there ?

Comment: If you just need a starting point then look at the code indention. For me it looks awkward to post that here. (But this is just the starting point)

Comment: why didnt you give a reference ??...can it be done by passing data to browser by $_POST['value'] ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put your php code like this

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['fname']))
    {

    $plain_txt = $_REQUEST['fname'];

    $encrypted_txt = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $plain_txt);

    echo "Encrypted Text = $encrypted_txt\n";

    echo "<br />";

    $decrypted_txt = encrypt_decrypt('decrypt', $encrypted_txt);

    echo "Decrypted Text = $decrypted_txt\n";

    }
```